# Como puedo sumar decimales en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask-plugin

Tengo un problema al sumar diferentes montos con decimales.

Estoy usando la librería jQuery Mask Plugin para formatear los montos a sumar, agregando la separación en miles (0.000.000). Al momento de sumar reemplazo los puntos por espacios para poder realizar la suma y luego con .toLocaleString() vuelve a agregar la separación en miles en el resultado q se muestra en otro input.

Lo que no puedo hacer es sumar montos con decimales. He tratado de usar la funcion .toFixed(2) para sumar con dos decimales pero no puedo o no sé en donde debería incluir esa función.

```js
function sumar_clientes() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".monto_clientes").each(function() {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
      total += 0;
    } else {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/\./g,''));
    }
  });
  document.getElementById('total_clientes').value = total.toLocaleString();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.number').mask('00.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="otros_1_clientes" class="form-control number monto_clientes" placeholder="Monto 1" onkeyup="sumar_clientes();">

<input type="text" name="otros_2_clientes" class="form-control number monto_clientes" placeholder="Monto 2" onkeyup="sumar_clientes();">

<input type="text" name="total_clientes" class="form-control number" id="total_clientes" placeholder="Resultado" readonly>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a 2 causas, primeramente la mascara que estas agregando y el reemplazo con la expresión regular, tu código es correcto, simplemente elimina estos elementos.

```js
    function sumar_clientes() {
      var total = 0;
      $(".monto_clientes").each(function() {
        if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
          total += 0;
        } else {
          total += parseFloat($(this).val()/*.replace(/\./g,'')*/);
        }
      });
      document.getElementById('total_clientes').value = total.toLocaleString();
    }

   /* $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.number').mask('00.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
    });*/
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>


    <input type="text" name="otros_1_clientes" class="form-control number monto_clientes" placeholder="Monto 1" onkeyup="sumar_clientes();">

    <input type="text" name="otros_2_clientes" class="form-control number monto_clientes" placeholder="Monto 2" onkeyup="sumar_clientes();">

    <input type="text" name="total_clientes" class="form-control number" id="total_clientes" placeholder="Resultado" readonly>
```

Comment: Pero si ingreso un monto con decimales utilizando la coma, no lo reconoce. En cambio con un punto, sí. Es posible hacer que reconozca la coma ( , )  como separador decimal?